# Has anyone else built Temporary Levels?

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

I have 3 levels named "temporary". I have seen the locked levels, like many posters here. I have been waiting for them to become available. I have built every level and unlocked every scene.  Every once in a while, I just try to "Add Level" and touch each type of level, hoping new levels would become available.

I had several million credits, and one day (around March 14) it just started allowing me to build levels. Now they are built and they do nothing. They all have the same generic "Death Star corridor" sort of look. They all say "Temporary" in green. I put one workers on each level, and it allows me to build 10 units. It takes about 1 minute to stock product and one minute to sell out.

Am I the only one? Can I post a picture of what I have so people believe me? I have millions more credits, and it will allow me to build more levels, but I don't dare to because I don't know what will happen with these temporary levels.

Answer (score 1):

Except for the Salvage droid levels from Kashyyyk and Csilla (2 each) and the Overbridge (Imperial level), I have a total of 138 levels, many of which I just built on 14 Mar. If I remember correctly, I think there were 36 new levels that day.

So fear not about these new levels or of losing them. What I would suggest is for you to ensure your app is updated, and then to restart your app after force closing it (no pun intended). Your temporary levels should now have proper names. In your case, since they are green temporary levels, they should be restaurants.

Not an answer to the question you're asking but a good tip nevertheless: I had 24 million bux and blew through them buying new floors (until I had only 1+ million and not enough to buy a new floor), then I saw that the remaining new floors were available at 1 bux a piece. If I had seen this ridiculous prices earlier, I would have held onto all my hard earned money and bought all new levels using bux instead. I'm not sure if it's a bug or not but I bought all the remaining floors using bux (before the devs rectify it IF it is indeed a bug). That was a very good deal :).

Comment: Thank you so much! I don't think I had force-quit the game since the 14th. That must have been it. Now I have 3 real levels.

Comment: Just to add to Han's answer, the "floors at 1 bux" were available to me only through the album, not through the "add new level" button, there they were for 45 bux